# Laptop fans always on while charging [20.04] [Dell XPS 9570]

Tags: dell, laptop, 20.04, fan, xps

The fans (gpu & cpu) are always running while charging, even on low temps. 
I am also unable to control the fans manually, because they kick in immediately (1 sec.) after each try. If I remove the charger, and switch to battery, the fans stop immediately.

I did not have these problems on 19.10 and 5.3 Kernel. Downgrading to 5.3 didn't work. TLP's Battery mode on always on also did not work. BIOS is up to date.

If you need more outputs, please let me know.

```
me@myself:~$ sensors
ath10k_hwmon-pci-3b00
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +33.0°C  

dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
fan1:        2685 RPM
fan2:        2782 RPM

BAT0-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
in0:          12.45 V  
curr1:       1000.00 uA 

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0:  +38.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:        +36.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:        +35.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:        +35.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:        +34.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 4:        +37.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 5:        +33.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

pch_cannonlake-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +35.0°C  

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +25.0°C  (crit = +107.0°C)
```

Comment: Hey Andi, welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Glad to see you have solved your own question. Please write the solution as an answer and mark it as accepted. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu ships with a faulty Nvidia Optimus driver, which sets runtime pm to off. 
I could fix it by using Powertop's "Tunables" tab and look at the "bad" ones. Then set the bad device(s), in my case 'Runtime PM for PCI Device NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]', to good.

Answer (score 0):

To extend Andi's answer slightly, I installed powertop using:

```
sudo apt install powertop
```

powertop needs to be started using sudo:

```
sudo powertop
```

ArchLinux article [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/powertop) discusses how to run powertop's tuning at every boot.