# Why does runtime power management switch from "good" to "bad" when switching to mains power?

Tags: 20.04, dell, power-management, battery, fan

As background, I'm trying to understand why my laptop always has its fan running when on AC power.

I installed and ran the `powertop` tool.

I noticed that various "tuneable" items shown by `powertop` toggle from "Good" to "Bad" when I switch from battery power to mains power.

My question is: Why do `powertop` tuneable items toggle from "good" to "bad" when switching from battery to mains power?

(...and might this help explain why the fan is always on?)

Laptop is a Dell precision 5520, running Ubuntu 20.04. Battery power management utility `tlp` is installed.

As further details, here's what's listed under powertop's tuneables tab when running on AC power:

```
>> Bad           Enable SATA link power management for host0                                                            
   Bad           Enable SATA link power management for host1
   Bad           Enable Audio codec power management
   Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-5 (i915 gmbus dpd)
   Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-0 (SMBus I801 adapter at f040)
   Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-3 (i915 gmbus dpc)
   Bad           Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-4 (i915 gmbus dpb)
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #0
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation CM238 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Serial IO I2C Controller #1
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
   Bad           Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
   Good          NMI watchdog should be turned off
   Good          VM writeback timeout
   Good          Bluetooth device interface status
   Good          Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-2 (Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter)
   Good          Autosuspend for USB device Integrated_Webcam_HD [CN045G28LOG00815B9B6A01]
   Good          Runtime PM for I2C Adapter i2c-1 (Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter)
   Good          Autosuspend for USB device xHCI Host Controller [usb1]
   Good          Autosuspend for unknown USB device 1-4 (8087:0a2b)
   Good          Autosuspend for USB device xHCI Host Controller [usb2]
   Good          Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1
   Good          Runtime PM for port ata1 of PCI device: Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
   Good          Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
   Good          Runtime PM for port ata2 of PCI device: Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode]
   Good          Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
   Good          Runtime PM for disk sda
   Good          Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9
   Good          Runtime PM for PCI Device NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M1200 Mobile]
   Good          Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #13
   Good          Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #15
   Good          Runtime PM for PCI Device Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2
```

A previous question (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1236285/laptop-fans-always-on-while-charging-20-04-dell-xps-9570/1397247#1397247)) mentioned the powertop tool when exploring a similar problem with their fan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because TLP uses two settings profiles that are automatically applied depending on the power source:

- Parameters ending in _AC are effective when AC is connected
- Parameters ending in _BAT are effective when running on battery

But of course this can be configured.

If you want the same settings for AC as in battery mode, then you can adjust your configuration (in **/etc/tlp.conf**) as follows:

```
TLP_DEFAULT_MODE=BAT
TLP_PERSISTENT_DEFAULT=1
```

Instead, you could also adjust individual settings, such as Runtime PM:

```
RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=auto
```

See the docs for details:

- https://linrunner.de/tlp/introduction.html
- https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/introduction.html
- https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/operation.html
- https://linrunner.de/tlp/settings/runtimepm.html
- https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/powertop.html